# How do unix systems call into an application?

Tags: c, arm, elf, assembly

I am currently implementing a C runtime library for the Arm64 platform, and I am unsure which assumptions I can make about the environment at the precise point that the application is executed (what the ELF file has defined as the entry point). With environment, I am primarily referring to the stack setup and the cpu registers.

I was able to piece together information by looking at the kernel source code, but not everything.

My question is: Is the calling convention into applications documented and/or standardized? I am looking for something equivalent to Arm64 Base Procedure Call Standard for example.

*I am posting this in the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, because I am interested in Linix specifically, and I assume an operating system may perform this call in anyway it defines as long as all executables conform.*

Comment: This being a **vast** topic with a fair number of exceptions. I suggest that you first read the manual for the **execve** function of the standard C libray, then eventually come back here re-editing your question with the points for which you need more detailed infos.

Comment: After looking into it some more, I agree. The scope is too great. Though the execve documentation is not quite the level of detail I am looking for, I found such information e.g. in the create_flat_tables() kernel function. I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that process initialization is not present in the System V ABI Standard for the Armv8 platform (Source: [ARM's published ABIs](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa)), despite being present in other versions of the standard.

It does appear to be a part of the standard though, and I was able to find the answers to the question [in the AMD64 SystemV ABI, v0.99](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf).

Summarizing the contents very briefly, process initialization consists of

- Putting argc, argv and envp (and their data) on the stack
- Floating point operations should be enabled
- Register state is not relevant, except for the stack pointer (and in some cases the frame pointer and a pointer for atexit())